# Avoid U-Turns in requested HERE Maps route

Tags: here-api

When requesting a multi-leg route via the HERE API (e.g. Point A to Point B via Point C), is it possible to prevent or restrict u-turns? I am trying to produce a map to be followed by a school bus, and u-turns are not allowed. However, I often find that the directions suggest to do a u-turn upon arrival at the intermediate points. I would like the bus to keep going straight after making its stop. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of the possibility to restrict this type of maneuver. 
Nevertheless, you can use *truck routing* in Here Location Platform for Enterprise, see the documentation here:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/download/routing_lbsp/6.2.32.0/Routing%20API%20v6.2.32.0%20Developer%27s%20Guide.pdf

It should retrieve much more adapted route for your use case and it might avoid u-turn.

Also, one final simple solution is to calculate route with alternative set to 3 (or make multiple call with other optimizations) and iterates through the different result in order to exclude routes that would include maneuver with a type associated to a u-turn

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, I have been using the truck routing which does indeed produce better results, but still a lot of undesirable ones as well. I hadn't thought of iterating on multiple result sets. Probably the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: There does actually seem to be a way using the waypoint type: https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-routing/topics/resource-param-type-waypoint.html
Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be available in the Javascript version:
https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/enterprise-maps/topics_api_nlp/nokia.maps.advrouting.GeoWaypointParameter.html

Comment: The waypoint type is to describe a multipoint route where you specify the type of waypoint. For example, you want to go from A to B via C where C is just a place you have to pass through (like a checkpoint in WRC). It's not a global parameter to avoid this kind of maneuver.

Comment: Yup, but the passThrough type places a cost on the u-turn and thus prefers a direct path, whereas the default stopOver type treats departing from each waypoint as a new trip and doesn't care if you head out in the opposite direction. I switched my code to use the REST API to calculate the route and specify this type, and this eliminates about 95% of the u-turns in my case. Doc says:
"180 degree turns are allowed for stopOver but not for passThrough. Waypoints defined through a drag-n-drop action should be marked as pass-through. PassThrough waypoints will not appear in the list of maneuvers"